# Plotting 3-D with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot my data to create a 3D figure using below python codes. When I run the program I only get an empty box without any figure (plot). Can anyone help where did I go wrong with the coding?
I have also difficulties to convert Excel files (xlsx) to csv which are needed by python to create figures of the data. I tried below but didn't work:

1. opened the file in Excel and saved it in csv (changed the file extension to csv but the data is not separated by commas.
2. opened xslx in notepad --> save as --> selected All Files and saved as csv. The extension changed to csv, again no commas instead the data remained in cells as original xslx file.

I would appreciate some advice on both issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

#********************** Entering the data automatically **********************
#File name
filename='T1T2Map_OW.csv'
data_raw = pd.read_csv(filename)

#Split and organize the data
#Relaxation Time T2
T2 = pd.DataFrame(data_raw, columns=['T2'])
T2 = np.array(T2,dtype=float)

#Relaxation Time T1
T1 = pd.DataFrame(data_raw, columns=['T1'])
T1 = np.array(T1,dtype=float)

#Brine Before CO2
Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine = pd.DataFrame(data_raw, columns=['Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine'])
Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine = np.array(Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine,dtype=float)

#************************** PLOT FOR DEAD BRINE *************************

fig1 = plt.figure(num=1,dpi=120)

N1 = int(len(Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine)**.5)
z1 = Increm_Poro_Dead_Brine.reshape(N1, N1)

at1 = plt.imshow(z1, interpolation = 'bilinear', extent=(-2, 4, -2, 4), origin="lower", aspect 
= 1, cmap='hsv')

plt.xlabel('Relaxation Time $T_2$ (ms)', weight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Relaxation Time $T_1$ (ms)', weight='bold')
plt.xticks(fontsize=9)
plt.yticks(fontsize=9)
plt.draw()
ax1 = plt.gca()
lbx1 = ax1.get_xticklabels()
lby1 = ax1.get_yticklabels()
for i in range(len(lbx1)):
    lbx1[i]._text = r'$10^{' + lbx1[i]._text + '}$'
for i in range(len(lby1)):
    lby1[i]._text = r'$10^{' + lby1[i]._text + '}$'
ax1.set_xticklabels(lbx1)
ax1.set_yticklabels(lby1)

cbar1 = plt.colorbar(at1)#, shrink=0.67)
cbar1.set_label ('Incremental Porosity (fraction)', weight='bold', rotation=270, labelpad=12)

plt.show()
fig1.savefig('Fig01_T1T2_DEAD_BRINE(AUBY).jpg', format='jpeg', dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Change extension of filename to ".csv" or open it in notepad, both not correct way to save it to csv-format file. For Excel file, you should save it as type "CSV ... (*.csv), and it won't work to open it and save as to csv in nptepad.

Comment: Please publish a small (3 rows is enough) sample of your data , this will help others to help you.

Comment: Also, I believe your problem is that you are calling `fig1` without adding anything to it. Try:
`fig1.add_axes(ax1)`, before you call `fig1.savefig()`.